# Test execution mode in spring 15 production

Tags: unit-test, production, order-of-execution

What is the default execution mode while deploying to production in current Salesforce release (Spring 15)?

I'm trying to avoid the deadlock while running tests that use Custom settings. I could use `Disable Parallel Apex Testing` but wouldn't like to do it on production. Is there any documentation reference about that?

Answer (score 1):

This Link would help you: https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_testing_unit_tests_running.htm

There is no problem in disabling parallel apex testing. It takes time to finish only. Only issue comes when using Custom Settings. You will not be able to run in parallel any more if you have multiple test classes that are trying to set up custom settings. It will throw exception.

> **Best Practices for Parallel Test Execution**
>
> Tests that are started from
>   the Salesforce user interface (including the Developer Console) run in
>   parallel. Parallel test execution can speed up test run time.
>   Sometimes, parallel test execution results in data contention issues,
>   and you can turn off parallel execution in those cases. In particular,
>   data contention issues and UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW errors might occur in
>   the following cases. When tests update the same records at the same
>   time. Updating the same records typically occurs when tests don’t
>   create their own data and turn off data isolation to access the
>   organization’s data. When a deadlock occurs in tests that are running
>   in parallel and that try to create records with duplicate index field
>   values. A deadlock occurs when two running tests are waiting for each
>   other to roll back data, which happens if two tests insert records
>   with the same unique index field values in different orders. You can
>   prevent receiving those errors by turning off parallel test execution
>   in the Salesforce user interface: